# Are these extra holes on the frame for disc brakes?

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, frames, disc-brake

My mtb (SERIOUS Rockville), which currently has rim brakes, has these holes at the back of the frame and I am trying to understand their use. Are these for disc brakes? Are these for disc brake converters?

[image]

Comment: No, but some of them might work as mudguard or rack mounts.

Comment: They look a bit lightweight for brake mounts.  Does the front fork have disk mounts?

Comment: Are the same holes on the opposite seat-stay as well. If so, they are for rack/mud-guard, as suggested by @Swifty

Comment: Looks like like decorations. Not in right spots for brakes and don't look threaded for racks or fenders...

Comment: I agree with @whatsisname Also, there appears to be a ridge that runs around the upper and left sides of the triangle of metal these sit in, which would make it difficult to bolt rack or fenders onto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’ll find similar decorative holes on the opposite side, which is an indication that they are not for disc brakes because those get mounted on the left hand side only.

The holes are mostly through quite a thin section of metal, recessed, which is probably too insubstantial to do anything useful, so no disc brakes.

The ‘Street’ model comes with mudguards and a rack ready mounted through the lower hole, which you’ll see is in a place with thicker metal and presumably the hole is threaded for this:

[image: Serious Rockville Street mudguard mount]